# How to stop Windows Update deleting the downloaded update files after failed installation

Tags: windows-update

When Windows Update failed to install an Insider Build, it freaking deleted the 3 gig file(s) that took so long to download. How do I stop this from happening again?

Comment: The only answer I know is [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-iso-file-using-installesd-image), to make an ISO from the down-load and use it for retrying the installation.

Comment: @AFH The 'install.esd' file does not come up anymore. Now Windows Update just downloads the stuff that changed to increase update speeds and lower bandwidth usage. Instead of the 'install.esd' file, some other ESD file which is somewhere about 400 MB is there instead (In the SoftwareDistribution folder)

Comment: I didn't know that: it worked for me last year. I also tried copying the complete `$WINDOWS.~BT` folder and copying back for a retry, but I cannot remember which file I used to reinstall (which may well now be different). I have had endless problems with W10 upgrades, as you may guess.

Comment: Normally Windows Update does not do that, only if it suspects the download is corrupted.

Comment: Windows Update already repeated the download 3 times already. Tf??!!